# "Missing Number" error when using "switch" in "boolexpr"

Tags: packages, errors

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{boolexpr}

\def \p{1}
\def \q{1}

\begin{document}
\switch[\p=]
\case{\q}abc
\endswitch
def
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above I get the following error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \bex@=0 truepart 
l.12 \endswitch
```

But if we change the definition to

```
\def \q{2}
```

or change the line to

```
\switch[1=]
```

it will be OK. But only change the line to

```
\case{1}abc
```

yields the same error.

Any idea why this happens? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Herbert has given a good answer, which solves the issue, but I'd say this might be regarded as a bug in `boolexpr`. I suggest you report it to the package author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems not to be well documented, but the examples show that a counter value is expected. You can fool the package by using `\numexpr`:

```
\switch[\numexpr\p\relax=]
\case{\q} abc
\endswitch
```

The problem is that one has to "announce" `boolexpr` the type of test to be performed in some way; also

```
\switch[\number\p=]
```

works.

Answer (score 6):

use counters instead of macros:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{boolexpr}
\newcounter{p}\setcounter{p}{1}
\newcounter{q}\setcounter{q}{1}

\begin{document}
\switch[\value{p}=]
\case{\value{q}} abc
\endswitch
def
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only `p` must be declared as a counter ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's quite strange. It seems that the expression before the equality sign must not be a macro. Using \value is a bit cumbersome, and I cannot even define a \v to replace it because that will yield the same error. Anyway, the answer doesn't give insight why this happens.

Comment: I now find `\pdfstrcmp` more suitable for my purpose. I originally want to encode strings into numbers so that I can compare them, but it's no longer necessary. Still want an explanation to the curious behavior of `boolexpr`. Won't TeX expand out the macros before compilation? What's different between macros and numbers?

Comment: @Marco: true, but it doesn't hurt :-)

Comment: @JunyanXu: *What's different between macros and numbers?* I think this is a new interesting question.

Comment: Another curious point is that the error only occurs when two expression are actually equal, illustrated in the first variation in my question. So the comparison can actually be done, but what prevents it from doing what follows?